# `Uncaught ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined` since Chrome 92

Tags: security, spectre, sharedarraybuffer

The usage of `SharedArrayBuffer` causes an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined` on Chrome 92. Why is this? How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedArrayBuffer` on Chrome desktop has been available for free until Chrome 91, but after 92, it requires a special state called "cross-origin isolation" aligned with Firefox and Android Chrome. To enable the state, you must send two security headers `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin`.

The discovery of [Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/) caused all browsers to disable `SharedArrayBuffer` but Chrome desktop could enable it again using the proprietary [Site Isolation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation). Chrome 92 is the version it shifted to the standardized approach.

As mentioned above, applying the two headers and enable "cross-origin isolation" is the way to go, but it may take you a while to set it up. As an escape-hatch, you can request [an origin trial](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) to allowlist your site to continue using `SharedArrayBuffer` without cross-origin isolation at least until Chrome 96.

To learn more about cross-origin isolation, read:

- [SharedArrayBuffer updates in Android Chrome 88 and Desktop Chrome 92](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/)
- [Making your website "cross-origin isolated" using COOP and COEP](https://web.dev/coop-coep/)
- [Why you need "cross-origin isolated" for powerful features](https://web.dev/why-coop-coep/)
- [A guide to enable cross-origin isolation](https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/)

Comment: In my case was the missing HTTPS protocol, that seems to be mandatory